# QT GUI thread stuck when reading from /dev/input/event*

Tags: qt, gpio

I am running a QT embedded application(4.8.5) on arm, and found an issue that causes the GUI thread hung.

Below is the push button code.

```
const char* PushButtonService::m_eventfile = "/dev/input/event1";
PushButtonService::PushButtonService(QObject *parent): m_stop(false), m_pressed(false)
{
    m_sockfd = open(m_eventfile, O_RDONLY);
    m_notifier = new QSocketNotifier(m_sockfd, QSocketNotifier::Read, this);
    connect(m_notifier, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(readBtnEvts()));
    m_notifier->setEnabled(true);    
} 
void PushButtonService::readBtnEvts()
{
    QLOG_TRACE() << "read evts";
    struct input_event events[64];

QMutexLocker locker(&m_mutex);
int bytes = read(m_sockfd, events, sizeof(struct input_event));
if (bytes < (int) sizeof(struct input_event)) {
    QLOG_TRACE() << "no evts";
    return;
}

for (int i = 0; i < bytes / sizeof(struct input_event); i++){
    if (events[i].type == EV_KEY ) {
        if (events[i].value == 2) {
            if ( ! m_pressed ) {
                QLOG_TRACE() << "Emergency Pressed";
                emit emergencyPressed();
                m_pressed = true;
            }
        }else if (events[i].value == 0){
            if (m_pressed){
                QLOG_TRACE() << "Emergency Released";
                emit emergencyReleased();
                m_pressed = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
PushButtonService::~PushButtonService()
{
    close(m_sockfd);
    delete m_notifier;
}
```

Here is the GUI frame:

```
m_emergency_frame = new EmergencyFrame(this, m_language);
m_emergency_frame->hide();

m_push_button = new PushButtonService(this);
connect(m_push_button, SIGNAL(emergencyPressed()), this,    SLOT(emergencyPressed()));
connect(m_push_button, SIGNAL(emergencyReleased()), this, SLOT(emergencyReleased()));

void MainFerryFrame::emergencyPressed(){
QLOG_TRACE() << "Button pressed";
m_emergency_frame->show();
m_emergency_frame->raise();
}

 void MainFerryFrame::emergencyReleased()
{
    QLOG_TRACE() << "Button released";
    m_emergency_frame->hide();
}
```

I can get the push button event at the beginning, but after some repeats, the GUI application hung , and the backtrace when the application is :

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb650a378 in read () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
#1  0xb69c81c0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
#2  0xb6632bf4 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**) () from /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#3  0xb6667f2a in QSocketNotifier::activated(int) () from /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#4  0xb6638106 in QSocketNotifier::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#5  0xb69cf818 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
#6  0xb69d123a in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
#7  0x000d7028 in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0x2044
#8  0x000d7028 in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0x2044
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Any clues?

Comment: as a side rant, `m_push_button` is a very misleading variable name.

Answer (score 0):

```
m_sockfd = open(m_eventfile, O_RDONLY);
```

I believe this will perform blocking reads unless `O_NONBLOCK` is set. This is due to the fact that when you are notified, nothing guarantee that 64 events are available.

You should probably execute `PushButtonService` objects in their own [Qthread](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/qthread/info).

```
m_push_button = new PushButtonService(0);
m_service_thread = new QThread();

m_push_button->moveToThread(m_service_thread);
```

You will have to move all setup of the `PushButtonService` constructor in a slot (ie `bootstrap`), and connect it to the start signal of the QThread.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But It is not the root cause. I've tried the NONBLOCK and extends PushButtonService from QThread. But it does not help. Please check the stack backtrace.